# How to do a newsletter / mailing list with Drupal 7

Tags: emails

I would like to make a mailing to a Drupal (7.4) community, sending an email to every user or every user with a specific role.

I would like to send this mails from my admin interface and I want to send mails with HTML.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) and [Mime Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) and/or [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) to achieve this.

Comment: This modules are not avaibles for Drupal 7 (there is only a devel version)

Comment: I'm afraid that these are your best bets at this point in D7. Although, someone else may have a better suggestion. There is also an email function in Views Bulk Operations http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations (Although the last I checked HTML emails were a challenge, due to a Drupal core mail issue).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use Organic groups to do all the group and mailing stuff.

Comment: Which is what I suggested in IRC earlier to you but you did not stick around long enough to follow up. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Mailchimp](http://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) could be a solution.
E-mails and tracking are done by an external e-mail marketing service, where html mails can be made or you can input an url to send as mail.
For now, this is the only available module with detailed tracking available for D7.